# Use provider with TabController

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

Hi I'm Trying to use TabController in a Provider, but I can't get the information on my other page with the tabviews. I guess I'm doing something wrong

I need tabs that I split into two parts. My tabBar in the parent and the tabview in another route to avoid loading N widget between navigation. But I can't communicate between the two through a Provider.

I tried with a ProviderScope and a Provider but the information does not update in my Tabbarview.

```
final tabProvider = Provider.autoDispose<TabController>((ref) {
  final controller = useTabController(initialLength: 3, initialIndex: 0);
  ref.onDispose(() => controller.dispose());
  return controller;
});
```

```
final controller = ref.watch(tabProvider);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: NavBar(
        controller: controller,
        builder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            NavBarItem(title: tabs[index]),
      ),
      body: const AutoRouter(),
    );
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, _) {
        final controller = ref.watch(tabProvider);
        return Expanded(
              child: [
                Center(child: Text('Tab 1')),
                Center(child: Text('Tab 2')),
                Center(child: Text('Tab 3')),
              ][controller.index],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the TabController is a complex object. Try separating the index into a separate provider. Like this:

```dart
final indexProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  return 0;
});
```

and...

```dart
final tabProvider = Provider.autoDispose<TabController>((ref) {
  final controller = useTabController(initialLength: 3, initialIndex: 0);

  controller.index = ref.watch(indexProvider);

  ref.onDispose(() => controller.dispose());
  return controller;
});
```

Accordingly, add `indexProvider` tracking to your widgets. And change its value.

---

**Or you can try** changing the type of `tabProvider`: `ChangeNotifierProvider` instead of `Provider`

Comment: Thanks @Ruble. I tried your solution but I have an error : Unexpected null value. However, I do have an index finger and a length that comes out of the ref watch

Comment: I can't use useTabController outside build method context. I tried with TabController and TIckerProvider but I don't have a result